# Definition of p-adic regulator and Minkowski theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-analysis

In "Cohomology of number fields" there is an interesting analogy between the Leopoldt conjecture and Minkowski's proof of the Dirichlet's unit theorem, in particular the homomorphism

$$j_\infty: K^\times \longrightarrow \prod \mathbb{C}^\times \longrightarrow \prod \mathbb{R}$$

defined by $j_\infty(x)_\sigma=\log |\sigma(x)|$.

In the p-adic case we have $j_p(x)_\sigma=\log_p \sigma(x)$ instead, for an homomorphism

$$j_p: K^\times \longrightarrow \prod \mathbb{C}_p^\times \longrightarrow \prod \mathbb{C}_p$$

Now, in the "archimedean case" the absolute value in the definition of the homomorphism is key, since it allows us to descend to the euclidean space

$$\bigg[\prod_\tau \mathbb{R}\bigg]^+\cong \mathbb{R}^{r+s}$$

and ultimately get the isomorphism between the Minkowski units and a subgroup of the trace-zero hyperplane.

My question is,

> Why is it $j_p(x)_\sigma=\log_p \sigma(x)$ instead of
>   $j_p(x)_\sigma=\log_p |\sigma(x)|$?

I guess the direct answer is that that's the way it shows up in the residue at $s=1$ of the p-adic zeta function.

But for instance, is the rank of the p-adic regulator matrix the same with both definitions, or can we show that it is strictly less if we use absolute value?

Comment: The value of $|x|_p$ is a positive rational power of $p$, in particular it is regarded as a real number. Otherwise which $n$-th root of $p$ is intended if you say $|x|_p = 1/\sqrt[n]{p}$ and want that "absolute value" to be a $p$-adic number? The $p$-adic log vanishes at $p$ (Iwasawa's convention) and in any case is naturally defined on the 1-units in $\mathbf C_p$, and if $x$ is a 1-unit then $\log_p x$ is interesting but $\log_p |x|_p = \log_p 1 = 0$ is not.